# Using R while loop to generate random variables

Tags: r, poisson, uniform, uniform-distribution

I want to generate a random variable X by continuing generating U(0,1) random variables as long as their product falls below exp(-2). Then my random variable X would be equal to the number of U(0,1) random variables that was generated minus 1.
I tried using the while loop to do it but not sure why the code does not return anything in my console. Please help me point out what I did wrong?

```
p <- 1
counter <- 0

while(p < exp(-2)) {
  u <- runif(1)
  p <- p*u
  counter <- counter+1

  X <- counter - 1
  print(X)
}
```

Comment: Why using p if it's always 1?

Comment: It's not working because most of the time your loop breaks at the first condition, since the probability that runif(1) < exp(-2) is actually exp(-2), which is pretty low. Your loop does not make sense as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## update

If you want to replicate the process by `100` times, you can use `replicate`

```
replicate(
    100,
    {
        p <- 1
        counter <- 0
        repeat {
            p <- p * runif(1)
            counter <- counter + 1
            if (p < exp(-2)) {
                break
            }
        }
        counter
    }
)
```

---

I guess you could use `repeat` with condition `p < exp(-2)`

```
p <- 1
counter <- 0
repeat {
    print(counter)
    p <- p * runif(1)
    counter <- counter + 1
    if (p < exp(-2)) {
        print(counter)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thank you! It worked. However, I face another issue using your code in cases when I need to generate multiple random variables Xs rather than just one X. Any suggestion on how I could do to overcome that?

Comment: @NganKD See the update

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding And that works perfectly! Never use replicate and repeat functions before, it's good to know. Thank you. Cheers!